# Downward Lowenheim Skolem over an uncountable vocabulary

Tags: first-order-logic

Downward Lowenheim Skolem says that there exists even a countable model for a set `F` of first order logic formulas, if

- the vocabulary and variables are countable
- `F` is satisfiable

Can one show a counterexample for the case where the assumption `countable vocabulary` is not fulfilled,
i.e. give an uncountable vocabulary together with a formula set `F` over this vocabulary, such that `F` is satisfiable but has no countable model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - take a language $\Sigma$ consisting of uncountably many constant symbols, and look at the theory asserting that these constant symbols all name distinct elements.

That is, we take the language $\{c_i:i\in I\}$ for some uncountable index set $I$, and look at the set of sentences $$F=\{c_i\not=c_j: i,j\in I, i\not=j\}.$$